# How to replace "★✿•" with their codes?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, html-parsing

I'm working on some web-parser on python and now stacked with special symbols like `★ ✿ •` and other, sometimes I get them in utf-8: `"&#226;&#156;&#191;"` and sometimes in unicode: `u"\xe2\x80\xa2"`. I have found the [table of them](http://copypastecharacter.com/all-characters) but the only thing I can do is:

```
set = []
set.append([u"\xe2\x80\xa2","&#8226;"])
set.append(["&#226;&#156;&#191;","&#10047;"])
for i in set:
    s=s.replace(i[0],i[1])
```

I write it with my hands.

Because I could not find the table that associate the left ones with the right.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a Unicode string containing a single character:

```
symbol = u'★'
```

It can be converted to the HTML syntax like so:

```
html = '&#{};'.format(ord(symbol))
```

To convert back, extract the number by stripping off the `&#` and `;`, convert to an integer, and then use `chr` (Python 3) or `unichr` (Python 2).

If you need to deal with input not from the above conversion, you may need to deal with hexadecimal ones, too, which look like `&#xZZZ;` where `ZZZ` is a bunch of hexadecimal digits. To detect these, simply notice that it starts with an `x`; parse the remainder with radix 16.

Furthermore, you may need to deal with named entities. See the last two paragraphs for that.

---

If you want Python to deal with the encoding of a whole string, you can use this:

```
text = u"I like symb★ls!"
html = text.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace').decode('ascii')
```

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent for decoding, and this also does not escape potentially hazardous HTML characters such as `<` (which may or may not be what you want). If you need to decode, perhaps use a proper HTML parser which will also be able to deal with named entities like `&clubs;` (♣).

If you want to deal with named entities and do not want to use a real HTML parser, there is a machine-readable (with Python's `json` module) [list of entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/entities.json).

Comment: thank you very much! and what about utf-8 case? btw, I think I could translate them into unicode or make some experiments with ord() and chr()

Comment: `u"\xe2\x80\xa2"` looks like it was misdecoded as `latin-1` when it should be decoded as `utf-8`; I think you'd want to fix that with `.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`. My answer described how to deal with `&#226;&#156;&#191;`.

Comment: I'm sorry, given `s='blabla&#226;&#156;&#191;bla'`
what should I do to get `'blabla✿bla'`?

Comment: @scythargon: Assuming Python 3, `re.sub(r'&#(\d+);', lambda c: chr(int(c.group(1))), s).encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace').decode('ascii')`.